# Input search bar from an array of keywords

Tags: node.js, forms, search, ejs

For my app, in nodeJS, I want to create a keyword selector, similar to the tags one in the Ask section of StackOverflow.
I know how to retrive an array of key words and pass it to the ejs section, but I'm clueless of how to proceed with the keyword searchbar

What I pictured, is that when an user is typing the first letters of the keyword, the matching ones start appairing in a section below, and the further the user types, the smaller the selection.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://github.com/albert-gonzalez/express-autocomplete

Comment: @Michael I was unable to make it run, I don't know if it's what I'm looking for .. Basically if it'a an searchbar that suggest words from an established list, yes it's something like this